# Cannot set the compiler flags in Xcode 4.3.3

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to set compiler flags to disable arc for some of the files and i am not getting the dialog box when i double click or press enter on one of the files.  It happens in a new project and old where i already set the compiler flags before.  All it does just becomes gray after i press enter and looses focus.  Is any one else having same issue or could i be doing something wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Comment: I seen this thread before.  i was always able to add the compiler flags but now when i press enter or double click nothing happens.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured it out.  I think its because i am using Macbook Pro with retina with resolution set to more text.  When i enabled assistant editor in Xcode and pressed enter to change the compiler flag the dialog box came out on the other side top right corner almost not seen.  Hopefully the next version of Xcode will support retina display.

Comment: You can also work around this by not having your xcode window maximised, move it down from the top of the screen

Comment: Thanks for posting.  The annoying thing is in xcode 4.4 it is still not fixed.  Hopefully it will be updated.

Comment: Actually this has been fixed in XCode 4.5 GM version.  It supports retina macbook much better

Comment: Lol on my Mac Book Pro w/Retina I can only see the dialog box when I enter "Mission Control" view, its about two feet off to the right of the screen and can't be moved. Lucky for me pasting into it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I still couldn't see the dialog box but did it blind-fully.

Copied "-fno-objc-arc" and then in Xcode, Enter -> CMD+V -> Enter... the magic was done. :)

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this in case someone stumbles across this answer when having the same problem on XCode 5 and none of the above solutions work, as happened with me.

In my case the problem was some kind of corruption of the workspace data. The problem was solved by deleting the xcshareddata/ xcuserdata/ and project.xcworkspace/ directories inside the project directory.

From a terminal:

```
cd <project_name>.xcodeproj
rm -rf xcshareddata/ xcuserdata/ project.xcworkspace/
```

Then restart XCode and the problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

And additionally if you're on a macbook pro without an enter key (the return key wont bring up the compiler flag box) and desperately are trying to flag multiple files at once... you just have to hit **shift + fn + return**. Just fn + return wont work - at least for me.