# Can't add compiler flags in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, compiler-flags

I'm trying to mark a couple of files as non-ARC. But for some reason, under Compile Sources in the Build Phases of my target, it won't let me edit them. Does anyone know what's going on? When I double click the column under Compiler Flags, the row that contains the filename is in turns grey.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Check this question out: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9865847/335858).

Comment: Like I said, I know how to mark them as non-arc, but it won't work. I've done it before, but when I double click, it won't let me add a compiler flag...

Comment: When I double-click, the row turns grey *and* a dialog appears where I can enter flags. Have you tried restarting Xcode or your computer?

Comment: That is rather strange. Do you have read and write access to the project files?

Comment: Yes I do have read/write access. I just shut down and booted back, and quit/reopened Xcode. Still can't edit them.

Comment: Do you have an extra monitor or  an incorrect resolution/configuration, or anything that might cause the dialog to appear off screen? Sometime it just doesn't focus to it despite the correct actions happening.

Comment: Well I can see everything just fine and nothing is wider than normal. I'm using a retina macbook pro. It shouldn't have any affect though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot set the compiler flags in Xcode 4.3.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315463/cannot-set-the-compiler-flags-in-xcode-4-3-3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the files are external from external libraries you have added to your project you may want to delete them from your project, re-add them and make sure you click the "add to targets" - "your app name" check box. Then try double clicking the row again in compile sources.

EDIT: (ANSWER)
If you're on a retina macbook pro, this may be your issue. I solved it by going to the compiler flags, hitting enter/double clicking on the one I want to edit, and typing even though I can't see anything happening. Hitting enter will then finish editing the compiler flag for this row (or rows if you do a multi-select).

Comment: They were added to my targets. That box was checked. Anyway, I deleted, and added it again, and still didn't work.

Comment: Think I found a link that may be the cause : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315463/cannot-set-the-compiler-flags-in-xcode-4-3-3)

Comment: Woah, that is super weird! I guess Xcode isn't optimized just yet for the Retina Macbook Pro. Thanks for pointing this out! +1